# How to fix "error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token" when calling a function that is declared as func ptr

Tags: c, function

I am trying to call a function that is declared as a function ptr I believe? Compiler Gives error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token

```
static void map_start(struct map_reduce *mr){

map_fn(mr, mr->infile, mr->id , mr->threadNum);
}

static void reduce_start(struct map_reduce *mr){

reduce_fn(mr, mr->outfile,(mr->threadNum));
}

//map_fn and reduce_fn is defined as these

typedef int (*map_fn)(struct map_reduce *mr, int infd, int id, int nmaps);

typedef int (*reduce_fn)(struct map_reduce *mr, int outfd, int nmaps);
```

errors are:

```
mapreduce.c: In function ‘map_start’:
mapreduce.c:87: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
mapreduce.c: In function ‘reduce_start’:
mapreduce.c:92: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
make: *** [mapreduce.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Those typedefs define a name for a type which is a function, you're trying to call a type which makes no sense. You want a function of type `map_fn` and `reduce_fn`

Comment: `map_fn` is not a function pointer, it is a type. How does it make sense to call a type? - it's like writing `int + 1`

Comment: If you have a function pointer, you need a variable of that type and that points to some function to call. That's missing in your code.